# Custom theme for AlertDialog not being applied

Tags: android, styles, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, app-themes

The common style for AlertDialogs is set in `themes.xml`

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AlertDialog</item>
</style>
```

And the `ThemeOverlay.AlertDialog` looks like this:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    ...
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButton</item>
    ...
</style>
```

However for one particular dialog in the app I need to use a different `buttonStyle` (textColor). For this I've created a style with a common style as a parent:

```
<style name="NewAlertButtonStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AlertDialog">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButtonRed</item>
</style>
```

And then the `AlertDialogButtonRed` looks like:

```
<style name="AlertDialogButtonRed" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

And this is being set when creating a dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.NewAlertButtonStyle))
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.dialog_body))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { _, _ ->
                    //doing something here
                }.show()
```

Howevere the style seems not being applied, the button text color is not red. What am I missing?

Comment: shouldn't you set R.style.NewAlertButtonStyle in ContextThemeWrapper?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, right, I'm using `NewAlertButtonStyle` in ContextThemeWrapper actually and put the wrong style in the question. Will edit it now

Answer (score 0):

Just set `R.style.NewAlertButtonStyle` in `ContextThemeWrapper`

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong one to the question, edited now. I am actually using `R.style.NewAlertButtonStyle` in `ContextThemeWrapper` but this still doesn't work

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You are speaking about the control buttons of the dialog itself, right?
They are using `android:buttonBarButtonStyle`, which is the correct style for you to apply in the dialog overlay.

But you may probably already have changed the usage of your AlertDialog material dialogs of some sort. In that case there might be a different style you need to apply (there I'm not sure).